# ChildView won't call my delegate method !

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a parent view called controller : *AskHome* and a child view called *record_audio* . AskHome display modally recod_audio, i implemented a delegate protocole so that i can send back to the parent view (AskHome) an NSNumber variable that i receive in the record_audio (the child view), but the delegate method isn't called at all :

so the chidView first

*record_audio.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@protocol sendbackQuestionIdDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)getIdDelegate:(NSNumber *)theQstId;
@end

@interface record_audio : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {
//my stuff here
//......
id <sendbackQuestionIdDelegate> delegate;
}

@end
```

*record_audio.m*

```
#import "record_audio.h"
@implementation record_audio
@synthesize actSpinner, btnStart, btnPlay, btnCancel, btnValidate, delegate;

/* I do some stuff, upload the sound etc....
....
....
*/

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
//i call the delgate, theAnswer is the string i received from the server as a response
[delegate getIdDelegate:(NSNumber *)[theAnswer intValue]];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //just dismiss this child view
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

the  parent view :

*AskHome.h*

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "record_audio.h"

@interface AskHome : UIViewController <sendbackQuestionIdDelegate>
{
//stuff here
}
//other stuff here
@end
```

*AskHome.m*

```
#import "AskHome.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"
#import "record_audio.h"

@implementation AskHome

- (void)getIdDelegate:(NSNumber *)theQstId
{
    NSLog(@"- ========= === <<<<<<   The delegate method was called >>>>>>>>>> - ========= ===  ");
    questionId = theQstId;

}
```

In the console i don't have the NSLog above, which means my delegate isn't called, why ? someone have an idea ? Thank you guys :)

Comment: Slved ; i forgot nick.delegate = self; whene i called the childView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you setting the record_audio's delegate? This is prob the issue that it's not getting set. (Debug thought and make sure the delegate is a valid object)

Also it's not the best practice to have delegate methods called 'getWhatever' . There may be a flaw in your design pattern and may be best suited to a singleton.

Comment: what record_audio delegate ? what i showed is what all i have in my code ... something is missing ?

Comment: @john in your record_audio_testViewController interface you have  "id <sendbackQuestionIdDelegate> delegate;". Where do you set this delegate?

Comment: oh sorry record_audio_testViewController is record_audio, i just rename it to make it simple and forgot this one